# regex code for getting only the first line from the text file using python

Tags: python, regex

Can anyone please provide me the regex code for printing only the first line of the data in the text file??? I am using spyder

i have tried may solutions but it prints all my data in every line ...last one helped me but it chose two lines. i just want the first line of my text file only till it encounters line break or till the text starts from next line.

```
import re

def getname(s):    
    nameregex=re.findall(r'^.*?[\.!\?](?:\s|$)',line)
    if len(nameregex)!=0:
        print(nameregex)


s = open('yesno.txt')     
for line in s:    
    getname(s)
```

In the output i am getting first two lines.
Basically i am trying to print the company name only which is mostly in the first line.

Comment: "Basically i am trying to print the company name only which is **mostly** in the first line." It seems like you're asking for an incomplete solution here. If you really want to do this, though, why would you read the whole file and regex it? `open('yesno.txt').readline().strip()` will read the first line and throw out the newline. `with open('yesno.txt') as infile: infile.readline().strip()` will do the same thing but also handle closing the file handle, which is good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file into a variable using `read()` and use `re.search` to get the match:

```
import re

def getname(s):    
    nameregex=re.search(r'^.*?[.!?](?!\S)', s)     # Run search with regex
    if nameregex:                                  # If there is a match 
        print(nameregex.group())                   # Get Group 0 - whole match - value


s = open('yesno.txt', 'r')                         # Open file handle to read it
contents = s.read()                                # Get all file contents
getname(contents)                                  # Run the getname method with the contents
```

[**See the Python demo**](https://ideone.com/bQIIJn).

The regex is a bit modified to avoid the whitespace at the end. See details:

- `^` - start of the string
- `.*?` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `[.!?]` - `.`, `!` or `?` char
- `(?!\S)` -  there must be a whitespace or end  of string here.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E.*%3F%5B.!%3F%5D(%3F!%5CS)):

[image]

Comment: the code is working almost fine , now i am getting output as ""company name none " . i getting "none" after the company name

Comment: @Kartikaggarwal You may, it depends on the input you have. I do not have the data, you have it.

Comment: in the input i have next line as my mobile no.

Comment: @Kartikaggarwal Great. So how can I help you more with this?

Comment: bro my text file is like first line :company name
                       second line :mobile no. .......
nw i want to print the firt  line only but i am geting output like :company name
                                                                                                  none
really would appriciate your help on this man

Comment: @Kartikaggarwal That's because your method does not return a value, but prints some text. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/bQIIJn). I just removed second print.

Comment: can you also help me removing the full stop after the company name as well?? coz if i remove full stop after company name it does not work.??i just want the first  line so that it detects the line break and prints only the first line..thanks in advance man

Comment: @Kartik You may simply strip the commas after with `nameregex.group().strip('.')` but you can also get rid of the phnctuation if you capture the part before it and grab Group 1 after, i.e. use `r'^(.*?)[.!?](?!\S)'` and then `nameregex.group(1)`.

Comment: if there is no full stop at the end of company name , your code does not work. is there any other way where i could fetch the first line of text file till it encounters a line break??help me man plz

Comment: @Kartikaggarwal Use `r'^[^.!?\n\r]+'`